# How to fix Lua error in scrapy_splash when running on docker?

Tags: javascript, docker, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I set up docker image for scrapy splash and I test it with many urls,
after some times I got an error when try the url (https://www.udemy.com/)

```
HTTP Error 400 (Bad Request)
Type: ScriptError -> LUA_ERROR

Error happened while executing Lua script

Lua error: [string "function main(splash, args) ..."]:2: http403


{
    "type": "ScriptError",
    "info": {
        "message": "Lua error: [string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]:2: http403",
        "type": "LUA_ERROR",
        "source": "[string \"function main(splash, args)\r...\"]",
        "line_number": 2,
        "error": "http403"
    },
    "error": 400,
    "description": "Error happened while executing Lua script"
}
```

Comment: Post LUA code??

Comment: it's not required to run the lua code, I use the docker tool

Comment: The error suggests that there is an error in your Lua code. If you do not include the Lua code you used, it may be hard to help you.

Comment: You can use Splash without using any LUA, but to automate events in browser you will have to use a LUA script. Splash itself is written in LUA. I would guess you're using one without realizing it or there is something wrong with your Splash install.  It suggests it happened while executing a LUA script which implies there is a LUA script your program is trying to run.

Comment: scrap splash running on docker how can i able to access the code?

Comment: this may be the reason for the error, url shows **403** forbidden error